# Specifying metadata in conllu.parse

Tags: python, parsing, metadata

I am trying to include metadata specifying in conllu files. I have tried the following code:

```
filepath = "data/streusle/problem.conllulex"
strfields = ('ID', 'FORM', 'LEMMA', 'UPOS', 'XPOS', 'FEATS', 'HEAD', 'DEPREL', 'DEPS', 'MISC', 'SMWE', 'LEXCAT', 'LEXLEMMA', 'SS', 'SS2', 'WMWE', 'WCAT', 'WLEMMA', 'LEXTAG')
meta = {'text': '', 'sent_id': '', 'streusle_sent_id': '', 'mwe': ''}
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    tls = conllu.parse(f.read(), fields=strfields, metadata_parsers=meta)
```

This doesn't work with the 'meta' as above. The specification in the parse function is:

```
T.Optional[T.Dict[str, _MetadataParserType]]
```

This is an example of reading a sentence:

```
# sent_id = reviews-001325-0004
# text = Hooray for Craggy.
# streusle_sent_id = ewtb.r.001325.4
# mwe = Hooray for Craggy .
1   Hooray  hooray  INTJ    UH  _   0   root    0:root  _   _   INTJ    hooray  _   _   _   _   _   O-INTJ
2   for for ADP IN  _   3   case    3:case  _   _   P   for p.Beneficiary   p.Beneficiary   _   _   _   O-P-p.Beneficiary
3   Craggy  Craggy  PROPN   NNP Number=Sing 1   obl 1:obl:for   SpaceAfter=No   _   N   Craggy  n.PERSON    _   _   _   _   O-N-n.PERSON
4   .   .   PUNCT   .   _   1   punct   1:punct _   _   PUNCT   .   _   _   _   _   _   O-PUNCT
```

It's clear that I don't understand how to do this. I think it would be very simple, but I haven't been able to find anyone who is using this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. There is a default set of specification:

```
DEFAULT_METADATA_PARSERS: T.Dict[str, _MetadataParserType] = {
    "newpar": lambda key, value: (key, value),
    "newdoc": lambda key, value: (key, value),
}
```

I tried creating a similar structure, with

```
meta = {'text': lambda key, value: (key, value), 
        'sent_id': lambda key, value: (key, value), 
        'streusle_sent_id': lambda key, value: (key, value), 
        'mwe': lambda key, value: (key, value),}
```

With this it worked. So I could examine the key information I wanted, such as in:

```
tls[0].metadata
{'sent_id': 'reviews-101972-0007', 'text': 'This sign in policy is posted by the restaurant “no reservation, sign your name here”.', 'streusle_sent_id': 'ewtb.r.101972.7', 'mwe': 'This sign_in policy is posted by the restaurant “ no reservation , sign~ your ~name here ” .'}
tls[0].metadata['sent_id']
'reviews-101972-0007'
```